# Filter items by category - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of posts that are organized by category. Currently it lists them on the page like:

```
Leisure
    -leisure post 1
    -leisure post 2
    -leisure post 3
Sports
    -sports post 1
    -sports post 2
    -sports post 3
...and so on (these are not the exact categories and posts, just and example of how they are listed on the page right now)
```

which is created with the following component:

```
const Posts = ({ state }) => {
  const postsPerCategory = getPostsGroupedByCategory(state.source);

  return (
    <>
      {postsPerCategory.map(({ category }, index) => {
        return (
          <button key={index}>{category.name}</button>
        )
      })}

      {postsPerCategory.map(({ posts, category }, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h4>{category.name}</h4>
            {posts.map((post, index) => {
              return (
                <article key={index}>
                  {post.title.rendered}
                </article>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

The `console.log(postsPerCategory)` returns an array with objects in the following image:

[image]

I've created a `div` that maps the `postsPerCategory` so that there is a button for each category. But I am trying to use hooks so that when each category button is selected only the posts from that category are listed. I am new to using hooks, so I am really lost on how to create the onClick function that would do what I am needing. So far for the buttons I have the following, which is already in the code above:

```
{postsPerCategory.map(({ category }, index) => {
  return (
    <button key={index}>{category.name}</button>
  )
})}
```

How would I create the function that does what i am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hooks in this case would be just for the category.name itself, so you can setup a hook like this:

```
const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState(yourDefaultCategory);
```

Then inside your button all you have to do is add an onclick event that calls setCategoryName(category.name) like so:

```
<button key={index} onClick={() => setCategoryName(category.name)}>
  {category.name}
</button>
```

For this to have any effect on the list you need to filter your map list by category like so:

```
{postsPerCategory.map(({ posts, category }, index) => {
        return categoryName === category.name? (
          <div key={index}>
            <h4>{category.name}</h4>
            {posts.map((post, index) => {
              return (
                <article key={index}>
                  {post.title.rendered}
                </article>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        ) : null
      })}
```

I haven't tested the above but it should work fine. You could also consider using filter instead of map. Will be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Do you know how I would include a default button for view all posts? Based on some other examples I have seen, it seems like I would need to push a "view all" button? I am not sure that is possible based on the console.log(postsPerCategory) return in the original image

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `state` for tracking whether each category is selected or not.

```js
const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState({});
```

You should initialize this state when the app first rendered. This can be done with `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const isSelected = {};

  const categoryNames = postPerCategory.map({category} => category.name);
  categoryNames.forEach(categoryName => isSelected[categoryName] = false)

  setIsSelected(isSelected);
}, [])
```

Then when the button is clicked, the checked state should be toggled, as follows.

```js
<button key={index} onClick={() => setIsSelected({...isSelected,
    [category.name] : !isSelected[category.name]})}>
  {category.name}
</button>
```

Finally, render the category if it is checked.

```js
{
  postsPerCategory.filter({category} => isSelected[category.name])
    .map({category} => {
      // render here
    })
}
```

Comment: what are the benefits of this solution over the previous one suggested?

Comment: Looks like in the previous answer, you can only display a single category, which is determined by the lastly selected button. I thought you wanted to display multiple categories when they are selected.

Comment: ah okay, thank you. I do only need one selected at a time, however it would be nice to be able to view all as well. I am not sure that is possible based on the console.log(postsPerCategory) return in the original image

Answer (score 1):

Based on the first answer, you can set the default category name as 'all', then check the value of categoryName==='all', if it's true, map all the postsPerCategory, otherwise check categoryName === category.name in the map function. This may not be the most efficient solution, but it works!

```
{
   categoryName==='all'? postsPerCategory.map(({ posts, category }, index) => 
     (
      <div key={index}>
        <h4>{category.name}</h4>
        {posts.map((post, index) => {
          return (
            <article key={index}>
              {post.title.rendered}
            </article>
          )
        })}
      </div>
     ) : postsPerCategory.map(({ posts, category }, index) => {
    return categoryName === category.name? (
      <div key={index}>
        <h4>{category.name}</h4>
        {posts.map((post, index) => {
          return (
            <article key={index}>
              {post.title.rendered}
            </article>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    ) : null
  })
 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a running sample link like codepen or codesandbox for better visibility.